# mySQL: How to select FROM table WHERE IN LIST and NOT IN another list

Tags: mysql, select

Is it possible to select values from a table, where they don't exist in one list, but do exist in another... or they other way around?

E.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(g.`property`) as `number`, g.`property` 
  FROM `foo` g 
 WHERE `theID` IS IN (SELECT `theID` 
                        FROM `tableofIDS` 
                       WHERE `theID` = '54252') 
          AND NOT IN (SELECT `theID` 
                        FROM `anotherTableofIDS` 
                       WHERE `theID` = '54252')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(g.`property`) as `number`, g.`property`
FROM `foo` g
WHERE `theID` IN (SELECT `theID` FROM `tableofIDS` WHERE `theID` = '54252')
  AND `theID` NOT IN (SELECT `theID` FROM `anotherTableofIDS` WHERE `theID` = '54252')
GROUP BY g.`property`
```

Alternativly, you can use joins which will perform better:

```
SELECT COUNT(g.`property`) as `number`, g.`property`
FROM `foo` g JOIN (
    SELECT `theID`
    FROM `tableofIDS`
    WHERE `theID` = '54252'
   ) id1 ON g.theID = id1.theID
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `theID`
    FROM `anotherTableofIDS`
    WHERE `theID` = '54252'
  ) id2 ON g.theID = id2.theID
WHERE id2.theID IS NULL
GROUP BY g.`property`
```

Comment: +1 The 'join'-approach is actually the better way to go. Was about to edit my answer to include it.

Comment: @WiseDonkey - notice both these answers have a GROUP BY clause..MySQL does a disservice to novice query writers by not making it a required clause.  You should try to get used to writing the GROUP BY clause because every other database REQUIRES the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @leslie Actually the OP's query will throw a error `Mixing of GROUP  with no GROUP columns is illegal bla bla bla`, since even MySql errors out when there is a query with a column & aggregate function, and doesn't have a group by.

Comment: well then which clause is it...there's some clause that MySQL does for you and I thought it was GROUP BY...hhhmmmmmm?

Comment: @leslie When you `SELECT key, value FROM table GROUP BY key`, other RDBMS error out that you need a `MIN()` or `MAX()` around the **value** column.. MySql however, won't error out, and will pick a random row. (unless the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` [option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is turned on)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't think it through but discovered 2 syntax errors. Try

```
SELECT COUNT(g.`property`) as `number`, g.`property` FROM `foo` g WHERE `theID` IN (SELECT `theID` FROM `tableofIDS` WHERE `theID` = '54252') AND `theID` NOT EXISTS (SELECT `theID` FROM `anotherTableofIDS` WHERE `theID` = '54252')
```

Edit: Changed `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe what you're looking for is just this:

```
    SELECT COUNT(g.property) as `number`,
           g.property
      FROM foo g
      JOIN tableofIDs i USING (theID)
RIGHT JOIN anothertableofIDs x USING (theID)
     WHERE g.theID = '54252'
       AND x.theID IS NULL
  GROUP BY g.property
```